# Regular expression validation in React Js for Input

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I have an input where I need to have a regex express validation. I have a requirement where I need to validate against a regex that allows alphanumeric and space, but not allowing space as 1st character done?

I am validating each character pressed on the input

Here what I have tried

```
var regEx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;

if (event.target.value.length > 0 && event.target.value.length < 256 && regEx.test(event.target.value) === true) {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

Comment: Maybe `/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)?$/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the Reg Exp needed is,
`/^(?!\s)[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/` OR
`/^(?!\s)[A-Z0-9\s]+$/i`
Explanation:
 1). `^` : expects the pattern at the beginning.
 2). `$` : expects pattern at the end.
 3). `\s` : matches a space.
 4). `?!` : negation.**(in the above pattern it indicates that the first character cannot be a space, i.e; `\s`)**
 5). `[]` : matches a single character.
 6). `+` : matches one or more.
 7). `i` : case-insensitivity flag.
Why are you calling function for each character input?
You can wait for user to submit and then validate. You can save multiple function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+( [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$`

I hope this line will helpfull for you

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
var regex=/^[^\s][a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/;
return (event.target.value.length > 0 && event.target.value.length < 256 && regEx.test(event.target.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$
```

\s - whitespace
^ - negates them all

This allows all the alphanumeric characters and it will allow the space only in the middle and at the starting of the word.

I think this helps your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

> /^[a-zA-Z0-9]/

[Read the docs MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)